# How to import a library “rmarkdown” using the AzureML package?

Tags: r, r-markdown, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm trying to import `rmarkdown` into `AzureML` for one of my projects.

This is the function I'm trying to upload into `AzureML`.

The `R.version` check is because the function is evaluated in the local environment before uploaded to `AzureML`.

```
fun <- function (b5) {
    if (R.version[["os"]]=="mingw32" && ! require(talection)) {
        install.packages(
            "src/rmarkdown_0.9.6.zip",
            lib=".",
            type="win.binary",
            repos=NULL,
            verbose=TRUE)
    }
    ans <- as.data.frame(c("Finished"))
}
```

`rmarkdown_0.9.6.zip` is in a `miniCRAN` library.

The following code, is the code that uploads `rmarkwodn` to `Azure ML`. Please note the line `packages`, which tells R to upload `rmarkdown` to `Azure ML`.

```
test <- as.data.frame(
    cbind(
        c(0.0,  0.3,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0),
        c(0.0,  0.0,  0.0, -0.4,  0.0),
        c(0,      0,    0,    0,    0))
)

ep <- publishWebService (
  ws,
  fun = fun,
  name = "Talection-fun",
  inputSchema = test,
  outputSchema = list(
    ans = "character"
  ),
  packages = c("rmarkdown")
)

print(consume(ep,test))
```

The code returns

> Request failed with status 400. Waiting 12.7 seconds before retry
>   Request failed with status 400. Waiting 33.6 seconds before retry
>   Request failed with status 400. Waiting 76.7 seconds before retry
>   Request failed with status 400. Waiting 234.3 seconds before retry
>   Request failed with status 400. Waiting 123.1 seconds before retry
>   Error: AzureML returns error code:
>   HTTP status code : 400
>   AzureML error code  : LibraryExecutionError

Any and all relevant suggestions welcome. Thank you.

Comment: There might be a problem with web service. Could you make sure that you have the correct credentials? Another solution that comes to my mind is to update to AzureML [last version](https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/AzureML#installation-instructions)